# Jquery Add class on mouse over and remove it with delay

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm writing a small script who, on mouse hover, add class and on mouse leave remove class. Remove must be with delay.

Following script just addClass and don't work on removeClass. I don't get error...

```
$(".result").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).addClass("current");
  },
  function () {
    setTimeout( function () {
        $(this).removeClass("current");
    }, 800)
  }
);
```

The same script, but withouth setTimeout, work...

```
$(".result").hover(
  function () {
    $(this).addClass("current");
  },
  function () {
    $(this).removeClass("current");
  }
);
```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks!

Comment: I assume it's a problem to do with `this` reverting the global object inside the callback (although I'm surprised because I've not come across this with jQuery and thought it must hard-bind the `this` to prevent this problem). If so, you can fix it with an arrow function: `setTimeout(() => $(this).removeClass("current"), 800)`

Comment: Alternatively, if you can;t use arrow functions you could try doing something like `var _this = this; setTimeout(function () { $(_this). ...`

Comment: @RobinZigmond the arrowed function work fine! Thanks!

Comment: @BenLonsdale i tried but seems don't work... thanks anyway!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside the setTimeout the context of `this` is different. In that case you can use the arrow function `()` as shown in example two or use `.bind` to bind the scope to the current context

```js
$(".result").hover(
  function() {
    $(this).addClass("current");
  },
  function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      $(this).removeClass("current");
    }.bind(this), 800)
  });

// with arrow function

$(".result2").hover(
  function() {
    $(this).addClass("current2");
  },
  function() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      $(this).removeClass("current2");
    }, 800)
  });
```

```css
.current {
  color: red;
}

.current2 {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='result'> I am the result </div>

<div class='result2'> I am the result2 </div>
```

Comment: @Brisk careful with arrow functions though, not supported in all browsers. You could also just use `.bind(this)`

Comment: It's supported in any browser less than 4-5 years old - which in practice means everything anyone actually uses, with the inevitable exception of IE. (I have no idea why people still use IE, but apparently many do.)

Comment: @TKoL oh thanks for the tip! Changed the script with .bind!

Comment: @RobinZigmond why people still use IE? Is a huge mistery!